# error: size of array ‘u’ has non-integral type ‘double’|

Tags: c++, arrays

i have the following code and i am receiving the error  " size of array ‘u’ has non-integral type ‘double’|"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>


#define steps 1000.0
#define time 1000.0

using namespace std;


int main()
{

double u[steps][time];
double a;
int data[10];

cout << "Please enter the value of ratio  cdt/dx :"<<endl;
cin >> a;


//initialize matrix u

for (int i=0;i<steps;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<time;j++)
            u[i][j]=0;

// fill matrix u

for (int i=1;i<time-1;i++) {
    for (int j=1;j<steps-1;j++){
        if (i==1)
        u[j][i]=0; //initial condition
        else
        if (j==1 && i>=1 && i<=50)
                    u[j][i]=50;
        else
            u[j][i+1]=pow(a,2)*(u[j+1][i]-2*u[j][i]+u[j-1][i])+2*u[j][i]-u[j][i-1]; //solution of wave equation

    }
    }

//create and open data files
for (int k=1;k<=10;k++){
ofstream data[k];
data[k].open("Data"data[k]".dat");

}

//fill files with data
for (int i=1;i<steps;i++){
data1<<i<<"\t"<<u[i][99]<<endl;
data2<<i<<"\t"<<u[i][199]<<endl;
data3<<i<<"\t"<<u[i][299]<<endl;
data4<<i<<"\t"<<u[i][399]<<endl;
data5<<i<<"\t"<<u[i][499]<<endl;
data6<<i<<"\t"<<u[i][599]<<endl;
data7<<i<<"\t"<<u[i][699]<<endl;
data8<<i<<"\t"<<u[i][799]<<endl;
data9<<i<<"\t"<<u[i][899]<<endl;
data10<<i<<"\t"<<u[i][999]<<endl;

}

//close files
for (int k=1;k<=10;k++){
data[k].close();
}

    return 0;
}
```

Is this error about the size of u ?And how can i overcome it?
Also, in this part of code

```
//create and open data files
    string k;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << k;
    filename += ss.string();
    string filename = "Data";
    for (int k=1;k<=10;k++){
    ofstream data[k]; 
    filename += data[k]; 
    filename += ".dat";
    data[k].open(filename);
       }
```

it gives me "filename' was not declared " and " ‘struct std::stringstream’ has no member named ‘string’"

I did that loop because i was trying to avoid the

ofstream data1; ofstream data2;.......
Can i make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: steps and time are double. Use ints, take out **.0**

Comment: you should not use a float value when declaring a carray, it works if you use #define steps 1000, but its better to use a const value: const int steps = 1000;

Comment: I dont really understand what you want to do with ofstream data[k], but k needs to be a const value so the compiler know the size of the carray, you can put ofstream data[10]; outside the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning `data[k].open("Data"data[k]".dat");`. In C and C++, you can join **string literals** by writing `"foo" XXX "bar"`, but this does not work with values that are not known until runtime. Instead, you have to use `std::string` and the `+` operator, for example:

```
std::string filename = "Data";
filename += data[k];
filename += ".dat";
data[k].open(filename);
```

Alternatively (if `open` takes a plain C character pointer):

```
data[k].open(filename.c_str());
```

Comment: @Lindydancer:Hello and thanks for help.I did as you said (i put them in the loop) and now it gives me "ambiguous overload for operator += "in filename '+= data[k]'

Comment: So `data[k]` isn't even a string? In that case you have to convert it to one. Search on `std::stringstream` and you will find tons of examples.

Comment: @Lindynancer: Hello,i converted data to string but it gives me the same error about overloading +=.If it easy to tell me what to do.It's ok anyway,i will not use this procedure.

Comment: Did you include the header file `<string>`?

Comment: @Lindydancer: yes,and also <sstream>

Comment: Looking at your code again, I realized that you don't want to convert `data[k]` to a string, but rather simply `k`. Do this with `std::ostringstream ss; ss << k; filename += ss.string();`

Comment: @Lindydancer: I am a bit confused now..It gives me other errors now, i updated my post at that part.I don't know where to put some declarations.

Comment: To start with, you can't convert `data[k]` to a string (as it's a file stream) so I suggestion you convert the integer `k`. Secondly, you should create *one file name per iteration in the loop*, now you start to create the filename outside (even before `k` is defined) and then make the name longer and looonger in each iteration. In other words, place everything related to the filename inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @lindydancer:Thanks for the help ,but it still doesn't work.Anyway,its ok.I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just change steps and time from 1000.0 to 1000

Like the compiler says, 1000.0 is of type double - a floating point value. Array sizes need to be integers. You can't have 1.5 elements anyway!

Comment: @BoPersson Can `2e5+6` be considered as `double` type?

Answer (score 0):

The error message "error: size of array 'u' has non-integral type 'double'" means that the compiler is unable to determine the size of the array u because it is not an integral type. The function expects an array of double, so the size of the array must be a double.